# LOCK_MODE_WAIT Configuration in Geronimo Datasource for Informix DB

Tags: datasource, informix, openjpa, geronimo

The application which we are currently working on with Informix DB and Geronimo app server, is throwing Lock Timeout expired exception since one of the "READ" operations is taking a long to time to complete the transaction and there is another UPDATE operation changing the record.

The approach was to increase the lock wait time out value, so that the transactions can wait for existing transactions to be completed.

The following configuration was made in the datasource definition for the informix database under the geronimo console.

**`IfxIFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT - 3000`**

However we are still getting the lock wait timeout exception.

Is there any other solution to increase the lock wait timeout value?

Comment: Can you execute a `SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 3000` as a statement (like you would an INSERT statement, for example)?  That seems like an awfully long time to be waiting; are you sure that the read and update operations are working sensibly?  Have you looked at the SET EXPLAIN output?

Comment: We need a configuration which will be applicable across the application for all transactions, hence was looking to manage it from the container level.

Comment: Have you considered a `sysdbopen()` procedure?  You could set the lock mode in that.